# Positioning content within a container

Tags: html, css

I want to make a console overlaid on a background image but cannot get positioning to work.  There is a container div with two overlapping child divs, one for a semi-transparent shade and one for text.

What is the proper CSS to fit the children inside the container's content box?

EDIT: the desired result is for the yellow word "content" to be placed inside the content area highlighted in blue in the image, and for the content area to be resized within the browser window with 50px margins (150px on top).  If you run the code, you won't see a blue box - that desired content location is illustrated by hovering over the content box (labeled 384 x 384) in Chrome's debugging window.

The desired result is:

1. the word "content" appears inside the content area of the container (shown in blue in the image),
2. if provided, more content text appears inside the blue content area with none outside that area,
3. the content area does not change size regardless of what text is inside it,
4. the content area does change size when the viewport is resized, so that it is always 100 px horizontally and 200 px vertically smaller than the viewport,
5. The browser window has a gray background.  The area shown in blue in the image should have a transparent reddish background and opaque yellow-green text.  There is no blue in the desired output, the blue just illustrates where the red should be located if the CSS were working properly.  The desired output is a gray page with a red tinted box and opaque yellow text.

Fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/dave2/381rnsy5/

[image: Console1]

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.25;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  color: greenyellow;
  border: 1px dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="bg">
    background
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `absolute` positioning? Also, your question is too long and better try to illustrate what you want and what you got.

Comment: I fiddled with this a bit and I am not entirely sure what the desired end result is. Your code produces a different result than your image - is your image the desired result?

Comment: Also not entirely clear to me what the desired outcome is, but if I've understood you correctly, I think you want to start off by changing your `#container`'s position to `relative`.

Comment: I can't tell what the desired outcome is either, but you need to set the position of the parent container to `relative` if you want the child to calculate its `absolute` position based on the parent. Also, with absolute positioning, you can set opposing sides. So if you just want 50px margins then you can set `position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 50px; left: 50px;`.

Comment: "An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except static."

If the container is positioned `relative`, it's content height is zero.  The desired content height is the viewport height minus 200.  That is achieved using absolute positioning of the container.

Comment: @Dave There are better ways to get control over the height of an element than using `position: absolute`. I might suggest that you clarify exactly what you are expecting as an end result.

Comment: The edited question tries to do that.  The desired end result is text inside the blue box, where the size and position of the blue box depends only on the viewport, not on the text contained within it.  If you have a better way to achieve that end result, I'm all ears.

Comment: `relative` position doesn't change the height to zero, its height is still based on its content, and the surrounding page behaves as if the element is still where it would normally be. `absolute` removes the element from the page flow and measures its position based on the next containing ancestor with a set `position`. If you're wanting to measure based on the viewport, use `position: fixed` or a container using `100vh` as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're going for?

https://jsfiddle.net/qjLbdtmv/2/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="bg">
            background
        </div>

        <div id="text">
            content
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bg,
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#bg {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.25;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#text {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  color: greenyellow;
  border: 1px dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The child divs can only be positioned based on their parent, but you need a `position` set on the parent for that to happen.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!    I'll need to do a little tweaking - Chrome shows a vertical scrollbar with a small amount of play regardless of size but the page should not be scrollable.   And the red background slides upward as the viewport height is reduced toward zero - kind of a cool effect, but not what I wanted :-).   Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! If there's a random scrollbar on the body, try setting `html` and `body` with `margin: 0`, and if you want the margins to be based on viewport percentage instead of pixels, you can use `top: 150vh` and `bottom: 50vh` as well. Good luck.